How to measure the distribution of eigenenergies of a cold atomic cloud in an optical trap?
I have a cloud of cold atoms in an optical trap.
For example a BEC or thermal gas of 87Rb (you can adjust the number from 100 to 10^6) in a harmonic trap created by some far detuned laser.
You want to measure experimentally the distribution of the vibrational levels of your harmonic trap i.e. the energy levels defined by your trap (given in first approximation by $\hbar \omega_{trap} (n+\frac{1}{2})$).
How do you do that?
I know the theoretical shape of the distribution.

How many atoms? What do you mean by vibration levels? There are no molecules there, right?

I have edited my question to answer yours! Thanks.
